# Convert an Integer to a string of words

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Convert Integers into Written Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/c-convert-integers-into-written-numbers)

I need to take an integer value and convert it to its english word equivalent (i.e. 4 => "four", 1879 => "one thousand, eight hundred seventy-nine") in .NET (3.5 to be specific).

I'm wondering if there is anything built into the .NET framework for making such a conversion.  Seems like it would be useful enough to belong there.  I haven't been able to find anything to do the job.

If it isn't included in the framework anywhere, does anyone have any ideas more elegant than a digit/place specific lookup?

Comment: this looks amazingly similar to an issue on project euler.

Comment: Check out this link: [Functional Fun: Euler 17](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/08/project-euler-problem-17-converting.html) for a LINQ solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words Check this question.

Comment: Nothing inbuilt. [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/Justin_Rogers/archive/2004/06/09/151675.aspx) is a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

string s being the input number

```
      const string input = "1023";

        string[] placement = { "thousand", "hundred", "ten", "" };
        string[] numbersToLetters = { "", "one", "two", "tre", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            int  digits = input[i] != '0' ? (placement.Length - input.Length) + i : 3;
            int result = int.Parse(input[i].ToString());

            var type = placement[digits];
            var number = numbersToLetters[result];
            Console.WriteLine(number + type);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything built in that I'm aware of. You're just going to have to do some digit-parsing and replacing.

I did find some examples on the net:

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/2743-Code-Convert-numbers-word.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/codesamples.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct function to convert and create word forms for you. You will have to write your program, where essentially you will have to hardcode values of all digits i.e. 1 one,2 two,...,9 nine. Then also you will have to take care of tens, hundreds, thousands, and then you will have to write logic to extract digits and append the words accordingly.