# How can I display money amounts in word form?

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help me make a money denomination program in VB.NET.
The problem is when you enter a number the program should convert it to word format.

If you enter in

```
'98534671.23'
```

the program should convert it to

```
"ninety eight million five hundred thirty four thousand six hundred 
seventy one and twenty three cents".
```

**See Also**:

[How can I convert an integer into its verbal representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation)

Comment: I don't know whether to vote to close or not seeing as how the previous dupe examples are for C# and not VB.NET. I know you can easily translate between the two, but I don't know if it could be considered an exact dupe.

Comment: Also, the other posts do not take into account the parts after the decimal point (the cents).

Answer (score 1):

[Convert integers to written numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/c-convert-integers-into-written-numbers)

You should be able to use this topic to help you. All you should have to do is convert the code from C# to VB.NET