# How can I convert between numbers and the words that represent them?

Tags: .net, text, numbers, nlp

Sorry if this is a silly question, but it is useful for my current lexical analysis project. Is there any built-in and preferably culture-based (language-based) function in the .Net framework to convert back and forth from string with numbers and the words that represent them? Like "1" <-> "one", "2" <-> "two", "3" <-> "three" and like this?

I know this can be made using a dictionary or a list with all the valid correspondences, but that is too much work if there is already a built-in function that one can use.

**Edit:** People who voted to close may have not understood that I was not asking how to convert decimal representation to strings, but the reverse operation: from a string to it's decimal representation. The links provided do not address this problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, this is not built into the .NET Framework. You will have to develop a custom algorithm to implement this functionality.

However, I recommend that instead of a dictionary or list (in which you will have to include *every single number* that you want to be able to display as a string), that you use something like the method described [here](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NumberToWords.aspx), which is far more extensible.

And obviously, you should keep in mind that you need to be *very careful* with this kind of feature if you ever plan on internationalizing your application.

Comment: Oh, I see even you have suggested the BlackWasp's Conversion code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a conversion (not to mention culture based). Take a look at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/c-convert-integers-into-written-numbers) for some implementations.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no built in function for that.

I remember that it was golfed a while back, you can check out some code to get a grasp of how it can be done: [Code golf: Number to Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words)

Comment: Not generally a good idea to use code golf code for anything but code golf :P

Comment: @Callum Rogers: That's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

This [tool](http://cid-e8f82acbdb9dc8f4.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/Sample%20Code/CSharpNumericToString.zip) by BlackWasp should be worth taking a look.