# Converting number to its string (alphabetical) representation in C#.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, numbers

as part of a project I am working on, I need to output the alphabetical 'name' of the number. This is better illustrated with an example.

> ```
> 960
> Nine Hundred and Sixty
> ```

So it'd convert '960' to 'Nine Hundred and Sixty'. Is there an easy way to do this in C#.NET? Also, if so, how easy would it be to apply the same function to a decimal number? I'm assuming if I can figure out how to convert a integer as above, I can just split the decimal number... so I'd have something like this

> 960.23
>
> Nine Hundred and Sixty (units) and
> Twenty Three (units)

Comment: Technically speaking, the and should only come in to play when there's a decimal point...or so I was taught in school.

Comment: This is a syntax nitpick, but the word 'and' in a numeric readout represents the decimal point - so "Nine Hundred and Sixty" would be 900.60 - not 960.00.

Comment: Agreed. Pedantically, "962.231" would be "Nine hundred sixty-two and two hundred thirty-one thousandths"

Comment: This sounds like a classroom assignment I used to give my C++ students, this isn't for an assignment is it?  Check writing?

Comment: Here is a gode golf answer you might be interested in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words/408776#408776

Comment: @Brad, @Erik, @Justin: That really depends on what dialect you're speaking: In British English that would read as "nine hundred and sixty point two three".

Comment: @Brad @Erik @Justin: That's an american-specific "rule" which as far as I can tell is not followed very much: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3518/american-vs-british-english-meaning-of-one-hundred-and-fifty

Comment: Thanks all - I'm well past being a student by the way!

Comment: @Chris then you you should be able to post your attempt at doing this.  Just seems like this has no real world solution.  Any solution would have to be cultural specfic for obvious reasons.

Comment: @LukeH, @Blorg - Thanks, I was unaware of the cultural distinction. =)

Comment: I'm replicating a report that needs to be generated, and in that report it displays the alphabetical representation of that number. But I'm hoping that I can miss that due to the complexity

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Convert Integers into Written Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/c-convert-integers-into-written-numbers)