# How to convert date to word format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have one date like 12/05/2012 now i would like to change that format in to simple string.

for ex.

```
string newdate = new string();
newdate = "12/05/2012";
DateTime Bdate = DateTime.ParseExact(Newdate, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

now my BDate is `DateTime`
ie. `BDate= 2012/05/12`

now i want to do something like

if my Bdate is 12/05/2012
so i want a string which is similar like "Twelve May two thousand twelve"

How can i do this?

Please help me...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? It is quite an unusual date format (and shouldn't it be `May the Twelfth, Two Thousand Twelve`?).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Only in the US. In the rest of the world, we pronounce it as “Twelfth May”. That’s the reason underlying the whole `MM/dd` vs `dd/MM` disparity.

Comment: It also means this question calls for a culture-aware answer, both for the numbers and the date format itself. This will not be trivial.

Comment: @Douglas not [only](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Middle-endian.2C_starting_with_month) the U.S., and not quite the [rest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Gregorian_little-endian.2C_starting_with_day) of the world, nor are they the only [options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date).

Comment: There is no build in functionality. You have to create a function that does it on your own. It is not so difficult though.

Comment: @NominSim: I was only referring to English-speaking countries; Asian countries would not use “twelve” or “May”. And it _[is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country#Map)_ only the US per most sources. Even your source states “United States, partially in Canada, and a few other countries [citation needed]”.

Comment: @amitvyas: See my answer. I have a working solution for you.

Comment: @Douglas I was just pointing out that "the rest of the world" doesn't necessarily use that format, trying to reinforce the notion that varying cultures need to be taken into account when you work with date formats.

Comment: @NominSim: If you’re referring to the numeric representation, then yes; I’m personally a strong supporter of ISO 8601 too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need to look at each date part and use a function to get the written equivalent. I've included a class below that converts integers to written text, and extended it to support `DateTime` conversion as well:

```
public static class WrittenNumerics
{
    static readonly string[] ones = new string[] { "", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" };
    static readonly string[] teens = new string[] { "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen" };
    static readonly string[] tens = new string[] { "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety" };
    static readonly string[] thousandsGroups = { "", " Thousand", " Million", " Billion" };

    private static string FriendlyInteger(int n, string leftDigits, int thousands)
    {
        if (n == 0)
            return leftDigits;

        string friendlyInt = leftDigits;
        if (friendlyInt.Length > 0)
            friendlyInt += " ";

        if (n < 10)
            friendlyInt += ones[n];
        else if (n < 20)
            friendlyInt += teens[n - 10];
        else if (n < 100)
            friendlyInt += FriendlyInteger(n % 10, tens[n / 10 - 2], 0);
        else if (n < 1000)
            friendlyInt += FriendlyInteger(n % 100, (ones[n / 100] + " Hundred"), 0);
        else
            friendlyInt += FriendlyInteger(n % 1000, FriendlyInteger(n / 1000, "", thousands + 1), 0);

        return friendlyInt + thousandsGroups[thousands];
    }

    public static string DateToWritten(DateTime date)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", IntegerToWritten(date.Day), date.ToString("MMMM"), IntegerToWritten(date.Year));
    }

    public static string IntegerToWritten(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
            return "Zero";
        else if (n < 0)
            return "Negative " + IntegerToWritten(-n);

        return FriendlyInteger(n, "", 0);
    }
}
```

> <sub>**Disclaimer:** Basic functionality courtesy of [@Wedge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3267/879420)</sub>

Using this class, just call the DateToWritten method:

```
var output = WrittenNumerics.DateToWritten(DateTime.Today);
```

The output of the above is: `Twelve May Two Thousand Twelve`

Answer (score 2):

This isn’t what you want, but the closest I can suggest using built-in functionality is [`ToLongDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring), which gives you the name of the month and is obviously culture-sensitive.

```
string str = bdate.ToLongDateString();
// Assuming en-US culture, this would give: "Saturday, May 12, 2012"
```

Comment: I don't need like this. i want Twelve May Two Thousand Twelve

Answer (score 1):

Suppose 12/05/2012 is a string, then you have to **tokenize** it into elements which separated by slash "/". E.g:

> "12/05/2012" -> ["12", "05", "2012"]

Next, you define yourself a rule which parses these elements to what you expect. Say, "12" is "twelve", "05" is "five" or "May", etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
string MyDate = "12/05/2012";
DateTime expected = Convert.ToDateTime(MyDate);
string MyNewDate = expected.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Check other date format on this site https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/23/date-formatting-in-c .