# Print Date as text ("fifth June two thousand four")

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core

I'm filling data in pdf with using pdfstamper.there is a birthdate i need to be fill.
with use of `datetime.tostring("dd-MM-yyyy")`  the date formated as shown in image.

```
 string birthdate = lead.LeadBioData.BirthDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                form.SetField("dob", birthdate);
                form.SetField("dobInAlphabet", "");
```

the dobInAlphabet form variable for date in characters.
how can i get birthdate in character as shown in image ?
there is any linq method that can  do that?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you want to get the human-readable date "fith june two thousand four"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert date to word format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565815/how-to-convert-date-to-word-format)

Comment: `Two Thousand Four` is a weird way to say 2004 in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer) for this.

`Install-Package Humanizer`

With Humanizer, you can do something like this:

```
var birthDate = lead.LeadBioData.BirthDate.Value;
var datePart = birthDate.Date.ToOrdinalWords();
var monthPart = birthDate.ToString("MMMM");
var yearPart = birthDate.Year.ToWords();
var birthDateString = datePart + " " + monthPart + " " + yearPart;
```

Comment: @BhavinVarsur you're welcome, consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem, that can practically represent your thanks.

Comment: Please use the tick mark to accept this answer. Thanks!