# Convert a string to int. Or Digit to text. ('1' to 'one', '3' to 'three', etc) In console Application?

Tags: c#, string, console, integer, console-application

I have a console application which asks a user to input a number using digits (1-9 and 0). I was wondering if there is a way where I can then convert that digit to a string of text.

Thanks.
I have found some code [online (here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/convert-integers-to-written-numbers), but I am unsure of how to implement most of it to a console app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert integers to written numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/convert-integers-to-written-numbers)

Comment: Seems to me that what you've linked to has everything you need. `string` works fine in console applications, funnily enough.

Comment: The code you linked to looks quite useful. Where are you having trouble implementing it? (The Stackoverflowers will gladly help you with specific problems, but they won't write your application for you.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd write a function

```
string DigitToText(int digit)
{
   if (digit < 0 || digit > 9)
   {
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
           "digit", 
           "digit must be between 0 and 9");
   }

   switch(digit)
   {
       case 0:
           return "zero";

       case 1:
           return "one";

       case 2:
           return "two";

       case 3:
           return "three";

       case 4:
           return "four";

       case 5:
           return "five";

       case 6:
           return "six";

       case 7:
           return "seven";

       case 8:
           return "eight";

       default:
           return "nine";
   }
}
```

Using a switch statement will save lots uf unnesscessary instantiation of arrays and although this may look verbose I think the resulting IL will be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The code you found there works irrelevant of the type of application. Just add the class there to your project and use it.