# Convert a DateTime to String representing the date

Tags: c#, date

How can I convert a `DateTime` to a `String`?

For instance, I want to convert a `DateTime` representing:

```
11/30/2012
```

to

```
November Thirtieth Two Thousand Twelve
```

Comment: why not use a Dictionary(intValue, yourStringRepresentation) ?

Comment: *there are no free lunch out there*

Comment: i also never encountered a free lunch ever, altough it would be nice :)

Comment: yeah, I know that will work. but I'm asking this since I think this (convertin numbers to strs) might be pupolar and there might be some ready code out there, even in .Net itself

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx (although the `Two Thousands Twelve` might have to be handled custom by you. (especially the plurality of "Thousands")

Comment: Not exactly a free lunch, but here are free sandwich fixings. Help yourself! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/convert-integers-to-written-numbers

Comment: I encountered a few. I ate them. Then they consumed me.

Comment: Apparently lunch is on @Nate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your google-fu is weak my friend, but you will learn:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b942f9/converting-dates-to-words-in-C-Sharp/ :)

Answer (score 0):

No luck here, but a partial relief:

String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"
[Source](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

The Day and Year string you will have to do the long way.  Day-of-Week and Month are available.