# How to convert integer to words in c#?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, integer

I get number(4,552) in textedit I need to convert it into Words "four thousand five hundred and fifty two"

How to complete this task?

Comment: Please be more precise when asking questions. Devexpress have nothing related to your task.
I hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation

Comment: @sri-hari, you may like to  search stack overflow before posting questions. There are multiple similar questions like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/convert-integers-to-written-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dislike when someone ask question without any effort to search google, there is a snippet of code from [Convert Number to Words C# Console Application](http://www.exchangecore.com/blog/convert-number-words-c-sharp-console-application/)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace NumWords
{
    class Program
    {
        // PROGRAM HANDLES NEGATIVE AND POSITIVE DOUBLES


        static String NumWordsWrapper(double n)
        {
            string words = "";
            double intPart;
            double decPart = 0;
            if (n == 0)
                return "zero";
            try {
                string[] splitter = n.ToString().Split('.');
                intPart = double.Parse(splitter[0]);
                decPart = double.Parse(splitter[1]);
            } catch {
                intPart = n;
            }

            words = NumWords(intPart);

            if (decPart > 0) {
                if (words != "")
                    words += " and ";
                int counter = decPart.ToString().Length;
                switch (counter) {
                    case 1: words += NumWords(decPart) + " tenths"; break;
                    case 2: words += NumWords(decPart) + " hundredths"; break;
                    case 3: words += NumWords(decPart) + " thousandths"; break;
                    case 4: words += NumWords(decPart) + " ten-thousandths"; break;
                    case 5: words += NumWords(decPart) + " hundred-thousandths"; break;
                    case 6: words += NumWords(decPart) + " millionths"; break;
                    case 7: words += NumWords(decPart) + " ten-millionths"; break;
                }
            }
            return words;
        }

        static String NumWords(double n) //converts double to words
        {
            string[] numbersArr = new string[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
            string[] tensArr = new string[] { "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninty" };
            string[] suffixesArr = new string[] { "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion", "quadrillion", "quintillion", "sextillion", "septillion", "octillion", "nonillion", "decillion", "undecillion", "duodecillion", "tredecillion", "Quattuordecillion", "Quindecillion", "Sexdecillion", "Septdecillion", "Octodecillion", "Novemdecillion", "Vigintillion" };
            string words = "";

            bool tens = false;

            if (n < 0) {
                words += "negative ";
                n *= -1;
            }

            int power = (suffixesArr.Length + 1) * 3;

            while (power > 3) {
                double pow = Math.Pow(10, power);
                if (n >= pow) {
                    if (n % pow > 0) {
                        words += NumWords(Math.Floor(n / pow)) + " " + suffixesArr[(power / 3) - 1] + ", ";
                    } else if (n % pow == 0) {
                        words += NumWords(Math.Floor(n / pow)) + " " + suffixesArr[(power / 3) - 1];
                    }
                    n %= pow;
                }
                power -= 3;
            }
            if (n >= 1000) {
                if (n % 1000 > 0) words += NumWords(Math.Floor(n / 1000)) + " thousand, ";
                else words += NumWords(Math.Floor(n / 1000)) + " thousand";
                n %= 1000;
            }
            if (0 <= n && n <= 999) {
                if ((int)n / 100 > 0) {
                    words += NumWords(Math.Floor(n / 100)) + " hundred";
                    n %= 100;
                }
                if ((int)n / 10 > 1) {
                    if (words != "")
                        words += " ";
                    words += tensArr[(int)n / 10 - 2];
                    tens = true;
                    n %= 10;
                }

                if (n < 20 && n > 0) {
                    if (words != "" && tens == false)
                        words += " ";
                    words += (tens ? "-" + numbersArr[(int)n - 1] : numbersArr[(int)n - 1]);
                    n -= Math.Floor(n);
                }
            }

            return words;

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a number to convert to words: ");
            Double n = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", NumWordsWrapper(n));
        }
    }
}
```