# Convert integer to number in text

Tags: .net, numbers, converters

This may be an akward question but is there any built in function in .net for translating an integer to a describing text?

That is, if i have the value `1` i want to print it as the string `one`. If the value is `22`, i want the string `twenty-two` and so on, or do i have to build my own function/algorithm for this?

Yes, the most common is to use 0 to 9 as explaining text and ten and above displayed in numbers, but I still wonder, and I guess I can't find anything about it since it's not possible? VB or C# does not matter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/convert-integers-to-written-numbers

Comment: sorry for repost, thanks.

Comment: Do you require localized text? Meaning, if you do this on a norwegian computer, would you need to get "To-og-tyve"?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That's my main reason why i wondered if there was a built in function for this in .net since then it would solve this problem automatically. But actually no - but if there were a built in function for this it would be "more right" to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [humanizr](http://humanizr.net/) library and then simply try like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(123.ToWords());
```

or else you may try to look at this: [Converting Numbers to Words](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/converting-numbers-to-words)

Answer (score 0):

You can wolfram it :

> [number name 123456](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number%20name%20123456)

If you use mathematica aka wolfram language, then you have interface for it and you can use:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-express-an-integer-number-in-english-words

To call Mathematica from c# you can use JLink.

It is not meant as most cost effective solution, but it is guaranteed to be right. For example **71!** is

> 850 duotrigintillion 478 untrigintillion 588 trigintillion 567
>   novemvigintillion 862 octovigintillion 317 septenvigintillion 521
>   sexvigintillion 167 quinvigintillion 644 quattuorvigintillion 239
>   trevigintillion 926 duovigintillion 10 unvigintillion 288 vigintillion
>   584 novemdecillion 608 octodecillion 120 septendecillion 796
>   sexdecillion 235 quindecillion 886 quattuordecillion 430 tredecillion
>   763 duodecillion 388 undecillion 588 decillion 680 nonillion 378
>   octillion 79 septillion 17 sextillion 697 quintillion 280 quadrillion

Comment: 71! = 850478588567862317521167644239926010288584608120796235886430763388588680378079017697280000000000000000

Comment: If i mentioned correct then I meant it is correct at least for 1 locale.