# Converting numbers to words and vice versa

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox, int

Let's say I have two text boxes, one contains a number and the other contains the number represented in words, like: 5000 and five thousands.

I want to do something so I can just write 5000 and the second text box automatically gets filled with five thousands or the opposite.

Any idea/suggestions how to do it?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary(Of Int32, String)`. It's a lot of work of course. Here are other approches (even in VB.NET): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/convert-integers-to-written-numbers

Comment: Oh it does require a lot of work. since it's not necessary i'll just skip it.
Thank you

Comment: There is a NuGet package called `Humanizer` you might be interested in

Answer (score 0):

To convert number to words, here you have [a full code](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18894.how-to-get-the-textual-representation-of-a-number-convert-number-to-words-in-vb-net.aspx).
Bur to convert words to number, what's the usefulness? anyway, it will cause many problems, cause of case sensitive and spaces.