# Continue writing in a second line of richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a function that converts an int to its actual string value, and it works constantly while I type the number in a textbox and the function converts it into a richtextbox.

The problem is that when it converts, i want to continue writing in a new line in the richtextbox so it can be printed as two lines on a paper.

Here is what i tried to do.

```
TextBox2.Text = "           " & NumberToText(AmountBox.Text)
If TextBox2.Text.Length() > 60 Then
    TextBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
End If
```

TextBox2 is the name of my richtextbox, and i chose 60 which is the average number of letters i want on my first line.

How can i let it continue converting the same number but on the second line ?

I want the output to be something like:

> Four Hundreds Twenty Three Millions Four Hundreds Twenty  -line1
>
> Five Thousands Four Hundreds Twelve                       -line2

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Number to text as many return points you could use this intermediate function

```
Public Function NumberToTextSplitted(texto As String) As String
'Append this to what you are are already doing
Dim rtn as strin = NumberToText(texto)
Dim words As String() = rtn.Split(" ") 
Dim result As String = String.Empty

For Each word As String In words
    If line.Length + word.Length >= 59 Then
        result &= Environment.NewLine
    End If

    result &= " " & word
Next

Return result
```

End Function

Comment: Trying that and ill tell you

Comment: The problem is that the function itself has like 15 returns..
here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/convert-integers-to-written-numbers

Comment: Oh i have just edited yours i am so sorry!
I have solved it, thanks to you

Comment: I'm glad to help :) Please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: Done, it sure did :)

Comment: Just one question: why did we write :
Next
        result &= line 

in the end ?

Comment: Imagine there is only one string on "words" arrays: "Five". In that case, it will return an empty string because you will never actualice "rtn" inside the loop. However, i have updated my answer to preserve only the last valid code, and I have modified it with a simplified version where you don't need that extra line