# display user input from do while loop C#

Tags: c#

I have some code below that is almost finished, but the last thing I want to do is for the console app to display the number they have gotten from the user

EX: if user input 1, 3, 5
the console will display

The number you have inserted are:

1. One
2. Three
3. Five

Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks

```
static void Main (string []args)
        {
            string again;
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Insert Random number");
                int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to Insert another number ?(Enter Y for yes /Enter any other key to exit)");
               again = Console.ReadLine();
            } while (again == "Y");


            Console.WriteLine("The number you have inserted are: ");


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: "Is it possible?" Of course it's possible. You need to store the user's input in some sort of list (like, perhaps, a `List<int>`), and then at the end, iterate over the entries in the list and display them, or join the entries in the list into a string (with, perhaps, `string.Join`). Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please attempt to solve the problem on your own and feel free to ask a question if you have a specific issue with implementing your solution.

Comment: if i understand correctly, maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213/convert-integers-to-written-numbers) will help

Comment: Of course, if your requirement is to translate an Arabic numeral (such as "1") to an alphabetic representation of that number (such as "One"), then you are looking at a **much** different problem, with a lot of interesting challenges around localization and translating the number into text, depending on the scope of the problem. For example, translating "1,001,010" into "one million one thousand ten" is actually quite tricky.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a place to keep all the numbers you collected. Given this code, you may be expected to use an **array**, but real code is more likely to use a generic `List<int>`. Declare it near the beginning of the `Main` method like this:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
```

Add each number to it after Parse()-ing like this:

```
numbers.Add(number);
```

Then, in between the final `WriteLine()` and `ReadKey()` calls, you need to loop through the collected numbers:

```
int i = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{i+1}. {numbers[i]}");
}
```

What you won't be able to do in a simple way is convert the digit `1` to the text value `One`. There's nothing built into C# or .Net to do that part for you. Since this code looks like a learning exercise, I'll leave you to attempt that part on your own.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this array is probably what i need

my real assignment is actually to record a dish user want to eat
and then display it as a full course menu
but simplified it should look like that question

but the structure shouldn't be that different right ?